# Django Post Signal on some remote DB

Tags: django

I have two different projects

#### Project1 settings

default - project 1 database

db2 - project 2 database

#### project2 settings

default - project 2 database

What I did to use serializers, models of project 2, etc  in project 1 .
I copied the complete app from project 2 to project 1 and registered the model in settings.py and also removed the migrations folder so that any time I makemigrations in project 1 shell it does not create any migrations for project 2 apps in (project 1 and thus migrating wont add any models of project 2 in project 1 ).

Now the problem I am facing is I have to use post_save signal on model of project 2 app that I imported in project 1. and get notified in project1

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Project2Model)
def project2model_save_hook(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print(created)
```

this will work only when this signal is present in project 2 but not in project 1. In project 1 this is never called when object is created in default db of project 2 or db2 of project 1

How should I proceed?

Comment: Regardless what the database are, it will never be called, since the first project can not register triggers on the second one, these run independelty. Signals do not have much to do with databases since these signals are triggered by Django itself.

Comment: So the only solution to communicate between the two project will be the apis?or something much better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signals are Django specific and they are only triggered within the same process. If you want to trigger functions/workloads across different projects, you need to start using some kind of event-driven architecture.

The most basic solution would be using a message queue like `rabbitmq`, `kafka` or even `redis (pub/sub)`. Here is a very simple example for your case:

- You create a rabbitmq queue named `model1_instance_created`
- You consume messages for `model1_instance_created` on project2
- You publish a new message to `model1_instance_created` whenever a `post_save` of this model is called on project 1.

But then there are other things you need to consider. Do project1 and project2 share the same database (hopefully not). If not, how do they sync data? What about data consistency? Then there is network latency and all the other issues related to microservices.

Comment: I actually use this method. But I got stuck when publishing a message to the queue inside "project 1". Because the RabbitMQ server needs to keep a heartbeat in the connection, but the process inside the Django signal can not keep running and sending the heartbeat.